# Find the first empty line and print line number

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I want to assign the first value of

```
grep -E --line-number --with-filename '^$' filename
```

to a variable. This command will return the line number of every empty line in my data file, which occur at the same interval as the first empty line like:

```
filename:122:
filename:244:
filename:366:
```

Is there a way to only return the line number of the first empty line - i.e. 122?

Comment: Why is there an `s` in `^s$`? I though you wanted empty lines.

Comment: Your title and text are not consistent. Do you want to print the line number of the first `blank line` or `empty line` ? An *empty line* consists of only a newline character. A *blank line* may have space and tab characters (but nothing else, except the terminating newline character).

Comment: The `s` was a typo, but thank you both for pointing that out to me. I still want the empty lines not the blank lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That'd be easier with AWK.

```
awk '! NF { print NR; exit }' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can limit the number of matches per file using `-m`.
Therefore, to generate a list of files and line numbers of their first empty lines use

```
grep -E --line-number --with-filename -m1 '^$' list of files
```

or equivalent but shorter

```
grep -EnHm1 '^$' list of files
```

Answer (score 1):

A fairly concise `sed` one-liner:

```
sed '/./d;=;q' file
```

You can specify the `-n` option if the extra newline isn't desired.

Notes:
The title and text in the question are not consistent. The *empty line* is not equivalent to the *blank line*. The `sed` command above will print the line number of the first *empty line*. If printing the first *blank line* is intended, the `.` should be replaced with `[^[:blank:]]`.